# Bad header display on iPhone 3GS

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone

I'm using this code for my website header:

```
<!DOCYTYPE>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#image_header   {
    border-radius:20px;
    user-drag:none;
    user-select:none;
    -moz-user-select:none;
    -webkit-user-drag:none;
    -webkit-user-select:none;
    -ms-user-select:none;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:50%;
    transform:translateX(-50%);
}
#header_image   {
    width:100%;
    height:150px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    border-radius:30px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header_image"><a href="/"><img id="image_header" src="http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/78e105390cf2426896c5fc38ae85a4f6.png"></a></div>
</body>
</html>
```

That code cuts the header image on both sides, left and right, when the browser window is smaller than the image.

I tested it on several devices and systems and it's working very well.

There's only a bad display on iPhone 3GS running the newest possible version 6.1.6. This is how it looks like:

[image: Wrong display on iPhone 3GS]

Does anybody know why this does happen? How can I fix it?

Comment: i wonder if there is still anyone actually using a 3GS for real

Comment: Me to, but it's better when it's fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem probably lies in using CSS's transform. You can check it over here:
http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d

Since it's 3Gs iPhone, i suppose you do check you browser's support.

Do try adding prefix **-webkit-transform: translateX(-50%)** else give a change on using position for transformationbackground-position: center;

Comment: Thanks, it's working. Is there also one with `-moz-transform-???` or `-ms-transform-???`… to have a higher support range?

Comment: Yes, try using "autoprefixer" with your build.

Comment: If you use the site http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d, expand all the browsers with "SHOW ALL". It is marked with prefix "-ms-, -moz-" for specific old browsers.

Do opt to use "autoprefixer" if you are using a CSS built like gulp/grunt etc.

Comment: Thanks, just for information. I additionally added this to my code: `-webkit-transform:translateX(-50%); -ms-transform:translateX(-50%); -moz-transform:translateX(-50%);`.